# mass inserting into model in rails, how to auto increment id field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model for stocks and a model for stock_price_history.

I want to mass insert with this

```
sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO stock_histories SELECT datapoint1 AS id, 
datapoint2 AS `date` ...UNION SELECT datapoint9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16, 
UNION SELECT datapoint 17... etc"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sqlstatement
```

However, I don't actually want to use `datapoint1 AS id`. If I leave it blank I get an error that my model has 10 fields and I'm inserting only 9 and that it is missing the primary key.

Is there a way to force an auto increment on the id when inserting by SQL?

Edit: Bonus question cause I'm a noob. I am developing in SQLite3 and deploying to a Posgres (i.e. Heroku), Will I need to modify the above mass insert statement so it's for a posgres database?

2nd edit: my initial question had Assets and AssetHistory instead of Stocks and Stock_Histories. I changed it to Stocks / Stock price histories because I thought it was more intuitive to understand. Therefore some answers refer to Asset Histories for this reason.

Comment: I would recommend that, if possible, transform that `insert statement` into a `rake` task using the Rails models you've created already. That way your application remains DB agnostic.

Comment: Do yourself the favor of developing with Postgres first if you use it in production, this will be minutes well spent.

Comment: @fmendez unfortuantely I get my stock price history as an array from yahoo finance api and it is called when a person adds the stock to their list of portfolios. Thus I can't rake each time. I need a method that mass inserts, thus the function I'm trying to create

Comment: @ThomasKlemm Glad I asked that bonus question as it just popped into my mind when writing the SQL statement earlier today. I'll look into developing for posgres but at the moment I'd like to know if there is a way to mass insert and auto populate the id field. I suspect this might come up for posgres developing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your SQL and be more explicit about which fields you're inserting, and leave `id` out of the list:

```
insert into asset_histories (date) select datapoint2 as `date` ...etc
```

Here's a long real example:

```
jim=# create table test1 (id serial not null, date date not null, name text not null);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "test1_id_seq" for serial column "test1.id"
CREATE TABLE
jim=# create table test2 (id serial not null, date date not null, name text not null);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "test2_id_seq" for serial column "test2.id"
CREATE TABLE
jim=# insert into test1 (date, name) values (now(), 'jim');
INSERT 0 1
jim=# insert into test1 (date, name) values (now(), 'joe');
INSERT 0 1
jim=# insert into test1 (date, name) values (now(), 'bob');
INSERT 0 1
jim=# select * from test1;
 id |    date    | name
----+------------+------
  1 | 2013-03-14 | jim
  2 | 2013-03-14 | joe
  3 | 2013-03-14 | bob
(3 rows)
jim=# insert into test2 (date, name) select date, name from test1 where name <> 'jim';
INSERT 0 2
jim=# select * from test2;
 id |    date    | name
----+------------+------
  1 | 2013-03-14 | joe
  2 | 2013-03-14 | bob
(2 rows)
```

As you can see, only the selected rows were inserted, and they were assigned new `id` values in table `test2`.  You'll have to be explicit about all the fields you want to insert, and ensure that the ordering of the insert and the select match.

Having said all that, you might want to look into the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem, which makes this sort of thing a lot more Railsy.  Assuming you have a bunch of new `AssetHistory` objects (not persisted yet), you could insert them all with:

```
asset_histories = []
asset_histories << AssetHistory.new date: some_date
asset_histories << AssetHistory.new date: some_other_date
AssetHistory.import asset_histories
```

That will generate a single efficient insert into the table, and handle the `id` for you.  You'll still need to query some data and construct the objects, which may not be faster than doing it all with raw SQL, but may be a better alternative if you've already got the data in Ruby objects.

Comment: I posted this before you added the SQLite3 comment.  The above example is from Postgres, and MySQL is basically the same except using `auto_increment` instead of `serial`.  It looks like SQLite3 uses yet another method for auto-incrementing fields, and doesn't support as much SQL.  Since you're going to deploy to Postgres, you're better off using that in development too.  Or you can use my activerecord-import suggestion, which will handle all the DB differences itself.